# How do I fix [PII is hidden] messages

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, pii

Hiding PII (personally identifiable information) in a production system is a good idea and sometimes a legal obligation, but in a development environment while debugging it is ridiculous nonsense that makes error messages worthless. How can I configure this to be disabled in my debugger but enabled in production?

Answer (score 2):

## In code (netcore on Kestrel)

```cs
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = env.IsDevelopment();
```

## On a particular computer

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <machineSettings enableLoggingKnownPii="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that it is against GDPR rules to use this in Production. So be careful: DO NOT TURN THIS ON IN PRODUCTION!!!